# How to set a conditional size scale based on name in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is a simple bubble plot for three character traits (Lg_chr, Mid_chr, and Sm_chr) across three locations.
All good, except that because the range of Lg_chr is several orders of magnitude larger than the ranges for the other two traits, it swamps out the area differences between the smaller states, making the differences very difficult to see - for example, the area of the points for for Location_3's  Mid_chr (70) and Sm_chr (5), look almost the same.
Is there a way to set a conditional size scale based on name in ggplot2 without having to facit wrap them? Maybe a conditional statement for `scale_size_continuous(range = c(<>, <>))`  separately for Lg_chr, Mid_chr, and Sm_chr?

[image]

````
test_df = data.frame(lg_chr = c(100000, 150000, 190000),
                     mid_chr = c(50, 90, 70),
                     sm_chr = c(15, 10, 5), 
                     names = c("location_1", "location_2", "location_3"))

#reformat for graphing
test_df_long<- test_df %>% pivot_longer(!names,
  names_to = c("category"),
  values_to = "value")

#plot
ggplot(test_df_long,
       aes(x = str_to_title(category), 
           y = str_to_title(names),
           colour = str_to_title(names),
           size = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 3) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(10, 50)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red",
                                "orange"))  +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) ```
````

Comment: Do you want the size to be set automatically based on the value (as it is now) but with a more exaggerated scale? Or can you just set it manually with `scale_size_manual` and give it the desired values for small, medium, and large?

Comment: a way to set it manually with something like scale_size_manual for multiple arguments would be great, but preferably for area not radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

You could use `ggplot_build` to manually modify the point layer `[[1]]` to specify the sizes of your points like this:

```
#plot
p <- ggplot(test_df_long,
       aes(x = str_to_title(category), 
           y = str_to_title(names),
           colour = str_to_title(names),
           size = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 3) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red",
                                      "orange"))  +
                                        labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())

q <- ggplot_build(p)

q$data[[1]]$size <- c(7,4,1,8,5,2,9,6,3)*5

q <- ggplot_gtable(q)

plot(q)
```

Output:

[image]

---

You could use `scale_size` with a `log10` scale to make the difference more visuable like this:

```
#plot
ggplot(test_df_long,
       aes(x = str_to_title(category), 
           y = str_to_title(names),
           colour = str_to_title(names),
           size = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), 
            colour = "white", 
            size = 3) +
  scale_size(trans="log10", range = c(10, 50)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red",
                                      "orange"))  +
                                        labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is good, but does not have the flexibility I need to see the difference in, for example, 70, 90 and 50 in Mid_chr.

Comment: This method also minimizes the differences in Lg_chr, making them look all the same.

Comment: Hi @MycoP, please check updated answer! You could use `ggplot_build` to manually set sizes for your points.